# Angular | How to set a style to a dynamic id with ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have this dynamic id and I need to set a style for it, but how do I do it? Is there a method?

component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let channel of channels | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize>
//Other code...
<ng-container *ngFor="let flow of flows">
            <td>
              <div id="flow_{{channel.id}}_{{flow.id}}" style="display:none">
                <i class="bi bi-check-lg"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
 </ng-container>
</tr>
```

I tried doing this in my component.ts but it doesn't work, it doesn't iterate the values correctly.

```
 idChannel: any;
  idFlow: any;
  check() {
    this.channelService.getChannels().subscribe(response => {
      this.channels = response.result
      for (var i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
        this.idChannel = response.result[i]['id']
        this.flowService.getFlows().subscribe(response => {
          this.flows = response.result
          for (var i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
            this.idFlow = response.result[i]['id']
          }
          document.getElementById('flow_' + this.idChannel + '_' + this.idFlow).style.display = 'show';
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Is there another way to do this? In the component or maybe directly in the html with some directive?

Comment: Have you looked at creating a CSS class and using [ngClass] to conditionally add your styling? Would this work in your case? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: I've seen someone did this, but I don't know how to implement it in my case. Do you have any idea?

Comment: here an example:  *ngFor="let item of fuel_types"
                  [ngClass]="{'text-white bg-ca-accent':item.isChecked,'text-ca-accent bg-white':!item.isChecked}">

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi Can you give me an example with my code? I can't figure out how this can work.

Comment: @JDev what is the classes tha you want to apply and in which cases or condition ?

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi it's an id `id="flow_{{channel.id}}_{{flow.id}}"`, but I can turn it into a class like this `class="flow_{{channel.id}}_{{flow.id}}"`. I would like to show an element just for these dynamic classes

Comment: soory your comment not clear but i think you mean somenthing like this : [ngClass]="{'flow_{{channel.id}}_{{flow.id}}:'hidden'">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251436/discussion-between-jdev-and-farouk-mhamdi).

Comment: Instead of `show` have you tried with `block/table` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from one of my current projects:

```
<input type="text" 
  [ngClass]="ingredient.drugName == 'DRUG NAME NOT FOUND'
    ? 'text-danger fw-bold'
    : 'drug-found'"
  name="DrugName{{index}}"
      disabled
      class="form-control"
      value="{{ingredient.drugName}}">
```

So what is happening here is that first it checks the conditional:

`ingredient.drugName == 'DRUG NAME NOT FOUND'`

if ingredient.drugName is `DRUG NAME NOT FOUND`, it will apply the `text-danger` and `fw-bold` css classes to the field, and the text will be red and bold. If not, then it applies the `drug` class, and it will do some other stuff that isn't important here. The point is that you can conditionally apply css classes to an element.

Here is a good article that goes over not only the simple conditionals, but also goes into some more complex examples: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/angular-ngclass-example/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - wanted to change the CSS of a specific element of the ngFor list so the user receives dopamine by clicking on it with a changing style.
If this can help someone I succeeded like that:

HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let activity of activities">
   // in case the div has the attribute "isTapped" we give it the class "active" with the [ngClass] and its ternary condition
     <div (click)="someFunction(activity)"  [ngClass]="activity.isTapped === true ? 'active' : ''"> 
     </div>
  </div>
```

TS:

```
  someFunction(activity) {
   // this precise div of the ngFor (and not the others) has now the attribute "isTapped" true
   activity.isTapped = true;
  // i put the attribute false after 100ms so the animation will occur again if i retap the div element
   setTimeout(() => { 
    activity.isTapped = false;
   }, 100);
  }
```

CSS:

```
 // whatever div with the class "active" has now these CSS parameters
 // (in this case, changing the background and giving it a quick animation)
 .active {
   background-color: rgba(188, 255, 177, 0.568);
   animation: cardify 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.28) ;
 }
 @keyframes cardify {
  50% {
    transform: scale(.9);
   }
 }
```